# ¿Cómo puedo agregar el contador de carga "% REAL" al preload "WaterBall"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando colocar un cargador de página con porcentaje “REAL” en mi web, y he dado con el siguiente código que se adaptaría perfectamente a mis necesidades y quedaría muy integrado en el contexto de la web:
[Preload WaterBall](https://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Liquid-Loading-Indicator-Plugin-jQuery-createWaterBall.html).

Necesito cambiar el contador manual, por  un contador REAL y que desaparezca cuando llegue al 100% (carga completa) y desaparezca, dando paso a la visualización de la página ya totalmente cargada.

Mi problema es que no consigo modificar el código para conseguir los efectos deseados:  Contador % Real y desvanecimiento al finalizar la carga 100%.

¿Alguien puede indicarme cómo modificar dicho código *.js para conseguir el efecto deseado?

Éste es el código:

```js
/* Código del plugin WaterBall */
(function($) {

  function drawSin(xOffset, color1, color2) {
    var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = config.cvs_config.width;
    canvas.height = config.cvs_config.height;

             // **** Cortar el lienzo interior *** /
    ctx.save();
    var points = []; //se usa para almacenar los puntos dibujados Sin curve
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.cR - 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.closePath();

             // *** dibujar la curva de pecado *** /
    ctx.beginPath();
    // Tome puntos sobre toda la longitud del eje
    var w_sX = config.wave_config.sX,
      w_waveWidth = config.wave_config.waveWidth,
      w_waveHeight = config.wave_config.waveHeight,
      w_axisLength = config.wave_config.axisLength,
      c_width = config.cvs_config.width,
      c_height = config.cvs_config.height;

    for (var x = w_sX; x < w_sX + w_axisLength; x += 20 / w_axisLength) {
      // El punto de la coordenada (x, y) aquí se toma por la fórmula "alta amplitud * sin (x * ancho de amplitud + desplazamiento de amplitud)"
      var y = -Math.sin((w_sX + x) * w_waveWidth + xOffset);
      var dY = c_height * (1 - config.nowRange / 100);
      points.push([x, dY + y * w_waveHeight]);
      ctx.lineTo(x, dY + y * w_waveHeight);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(w_axisLength, c_height);
    ctx.lineTo(w_sX, c_height);
    ctx.lineTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, c_height, c_width, points[points.length - 1][1]);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, color1);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, color2);
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    // ***Dibujar texto porcentual*** /
    if (!config.isLoading) {
      ctx.save();
      var size = 0.4 * config.circle_config.cR;
      ctx.font = size + 'px Microsoft Yahei';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillStyle = config.textColorRange[getIndex.call(this)];
      ctx.fillText(~~config.nowRange + '%', config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.r + size / 2);
      ctx.restore();
    }
    return canvas;
  }

  function drawCircle() {
    var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = config.cvs_config.width;
    canvas.height = config.cvs_config.height;
    ctx.lineWidth = config.lineWidth;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = config.circle_line_color[getIndex.call(this)];
    ctx.arc(config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.cR, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    return canvas;
  }

  function getIndex() {
    var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
    for (var i = 0, data = config.data_range; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (config.nowRange < data[i]) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return data.length - 1;
  }

  var methods = {
    init: function(config) {
      return this.each(function() {             // Usa el método de datos jQuery para rastrear variables para cada elemento            
        var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('waterBall'),
          _config = {
            cvs_config: {
              width: 220, // lienzo largo
              height: 220 // altura del lienzo
            },
            wave_config: {
              sX: 0, // desplazamiento del eje x
              sY: 220 / 2,
              waveWidth: 0.015, // ancho de onda
              waveHeight: 5, // altura de ola
              axisLength: 220, // Longitud del eje
              speed: 0.09, // velocidad de onda
              xOffset: 0
            },
            circle_config: {
              r: 220 / 2, // centro del círculo
              cR: 220 / 2 - 5 // Radio
            },
            isLoading: false, // No muestra texto porcentual cuando isLoading es verdadero
            nowRange: 0,
            targetRange: 0,
            lineWidth: 2, // Ancho de línea circular
            data_range: [60, 80, 100], // rango de umbral de datos
            textColorRange: ['#fe5022', '#fff', '#fff'], // gama de colores de diferentes textos de umbral
            circle_line_color: ['#fe3702', '#ffa200', '#4ed752'], // diferente color de círculo de umbral
            main_backcolor_range: [
              ['#fe5e21', '#f98957'],
              ['#ffb30c', '#f7d35a'],
              ['#2ed351', '#8ced6c']
            ], // Gradiente
            backcolor_range: [
              ['#f76b3b', '#f14f17'],
              ['#f4d672', '#ffb50d'],
              ['#43ea83', '#12ce55']
            ]
          };
        if (!data) {
          var wave_config = {},
            circle_config = {};
          if (config.cvs_config) {
            wave_config = {
              sY: config.cvs_config.width / 2,
              axisLength: config.cvs_config.width
            };
            circle_config = {
              r: config.cvs_config.width / 2,
              cR: config.cvs_config.width / 2 - 5
            };
          }

          $.extend(true, _config, {
            wave_config: wave_config,
            circle_config: circle_config
          }, config);
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = _config.cvs_config.width;
          canvas.height = _config.cvs_config.height;
          $this.html("").html($(canvas));
          $this.data('waterBall', {
            canvas: canvas,
            target: $this,
            config: _config
          });
          methods.render.apply($this);
        }
      });
    },
    destroy: function() {},
    updateRange: function(newVal) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('waterBall');
        if (!data) return;
        var config = $this.data('waterBall').config;
        config.targetRange = 0;
        config.nowRange = 0;
        config.isLoading = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          config.targetRange = newVal;
        }, 0);
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
      var _canvas = this.data('waterBall').canvas;
      var w_sX = config.wave_config.sX,
        xOffset = config.wave_config.xOffset,
        bg_color1 = config.backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][0],
        bg_color2 = config.backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][1],
        main_bg_color1 = config.main_backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][0],
        main_bg_color2 = config.main_backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][1],
        ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');

      var cvs1 = drawCircle.call(this);

      if (config.nowRange <= config.targetRange) {
        var tmp = 1;
        config.nowRange += tmp;
      }

      if (config.nowRange > config.targetRange) {
        var tmp = 1;
        config.nowRange -= tmp;
      }
      var cvs2 = drawSin.call(this, xOffset + 40, bg_color1, bg_color2);
      var cvs3 = drawSin.call(this, -40 + xOffset, main_bg_color1, main_bg_color2);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, config.cvs_config.width, config.cvs_config.height);
      ctx.drawImage(cvs1, 0, 0);
      ctx.drawImage(cvs2, 0, 0);
      ctx.drawImage(cvs3, 0, 0);
      delete cvs1;
      delete cvs2;
      delete cvs3;

      config.wave_config.xOffset += config.wave_config.speed;
      requestAnimationFrame(methods.render.bind(this));
    }
  };
  $.fn.createWaterBall = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + 'does not exits on jQuery.createWaterBall');
    }
  };
})(jQuery);




/* Código del usuario */
var loadingEle = $('.loading');
var loading_width = loadingEle.width(),
  loading_height = loadingEle.height();
$('.loading').createWaterBall({
  cvs_config: {
    width: loading_width,
    height: loading_height
  },
  wave_config: {
    waveWidth: 0.02,
    waveHeight: 5
  },
  data_range: [30, 70, 100],
  isLoading: true,
  nowRange: 70,
  targetRange: 70
});
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.loading').createWaterBall('updateRange', 80);
}, 1000);
$('.waterBall1').createWaterBall({
  csv_config: {
    width: $('.waterBall1').width(),
    height: $('.waterBall1').height()
  },
  wave_config: {
    waveWidth: 0.02,
    waveHeight: 5
  },
  data_range: [40, 50, 100],
  targetRange: 45
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery createWaterBall Plugin Demos</h1>
<div class="waterBall1" style="width: 200px;height:200px; float:left"></div>
```

Comment: Aqui nadie te hará tu trabajo, deberías decir por qué fallas,  que has intentado y colocar un código que sea reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Miré la página que pone que es [oficial para el plugin](https://github.com/CoolCola/createWaterBall) (y [la que se enlaza](http://blog.csdn.net/lecepin/article/details/53536445) desde allí) y no tiene nada de información. Casi parece más un programador que ha combinado dos plugins/scripts diferentes para formar ese (y no sé cómo de actualizado está).

He hecho un par de cambios en el código que compartiste, en particular en el método `updateRange` (lee los comentarios para más detalles). Pero no quiero hacer más cambios porque no es mi plugin):

```
updateRange: function(newVal) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      data = $this.data('waterBall');
    if (!data) return;
    var config = $this.data('waterBall').config;
    config.targetRange = 0;
    // línea comentada para evitar que se actualice desde 0 cada vez
    //config.nowRange = 0; 
    config.isLoading = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      config.targetRange = newVal;
    }, 0);

    // código que se ejecuta cuando termina de cargar 
    if (newVal == 100) {
      // hacemos fadeout del loader cuando termine la animación
      setTimeout(function() {
        $this.fadeOut();
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
},
```

Con esos cambios:

1. Cuando se actualiza un porcentaje, se comienza desde el punto en el que se encontraba y no desde 0.
2. Cuando se llega al final (porcentaje 100), entonces se realiza una acción (en particular se oculta el elemento de carga, pero puedes cambiarlo a lo que quieras).

Entonces la idea es que inicies el cargador como lo estás haciendo ya:

```
$('.waterBall1').createWaterBall({
  csv_config: {
    width: $('.waterBall1').width(),
    height: $('.waterBall1').height()
  },
  wave_config: {
    waveWidth: 0.02,
    waveHeight: 5
  },
  data_range: [40, 50, 100],
  targetRange: 45
});
```

Y cada vez que se cargue algo grande lo actualices al valor que quieras usando el método `updateRange`:

```
$('.waterBall1').createWaterBall('updateRange', NUEVO_PORCENTAJE);
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando. Lo que hace es cargar una página con 3 imágenes aleatorias. Cuando se carga la página se considera que se ha cargado un 25%, y con cada imagen se añadirá un 25% más. En un ejemplo real, lo que se haría es calcular el número de imágenes y ajustar los porcentajes acorde a eso.

```js
/* Código del plugin WaterBall */
(function($) {

  function drawSin(xOffset, color1, color2) {
    var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = config.cvs_config.width;
    canvas.height = config.cvs_config.height;

             // **** Cortar el lienzo interior *** /
    ctx.save();
    var points = []; //se usa para almacenar los puntos dibujados Sin curve
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.cR - 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.closePath();

             // *** dibujar la curva de pecado *** /
    ctx.beginPath();
    // Tome puntos sobre toda la longitud del eje
    var w_sX = config.wave_config.sX,
      w_waveWidth = config.wave_config.waveWidth,
      w_waveHeight = config.wave_config.waveHeight,
      w_axisLength = config.wave_config.axisLength,
      c_width = config.cvs_config.width,
      c_height = config.cvs_config.height;

    for (var x = w_sX; x < w_sX + w_axisLength; x += 20 / w_axisLength) {
      // El punto de la coordenada (x, y) aquí se toma por la fórmula "alta amplitud * sin (x * ancho de amplitud + desplazamiento de amplitud)"
      var y = -Math.sin((w_sX + x) * w_waveWidth + xOffset);
      var dY = c_height * (1 - config.nowRange / 100);
      points.push([x, dY + y * w_waveHeight]);
      ctx.lineTo(x, dY + y * w_waveHeight);
    }
    ctx.lineTo(w_axisLength, c_height);
    ctx.lineTo(w_sX, c_height);
    ctx.lineTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, c_height, c_width, points[points.length - 1][1]);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, color1);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, color2);
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    // ***Dibujar texto porcentual*** /
    if (!config.isLoading) {
      ctx.save();
      var size = 0.4 * config.circle_config.cR;
      ctx.font = size + 'px Microsoft Yahei';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillStyle = config.textColorRange[getIndex.call(this)];
      ctx.fillText(~~config.nowRange + '%', config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.r + size / 2);
      ctx.restore();
    }
    return canvas;
  }

  function drawCircle() {
    var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = config.cvs_config.width;
    canvas.height = config.cvs_config.height;
    ctx.lineWidth = config.lineWidth;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = config.circle_line_color[getIndex.call(this)];
    ctx.arc(config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.r, config.circle_config.cR, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    return canvas;
  }

  function getIndex() {
    var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
    for (var i = 0, data = config.data_range; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (config.nowRange < data[i]) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return data.length - 1;
  }

  var methods = {
    init: function(config) {
      return this.each(function() {             // Usa el método de datos jQuery para rastrear variables para cada elemento            
        var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('waterBall'),
          _config = {
            cvs_config: {
              width: 220, // lienzo largo
              height: 220 // altura del lienzo
            },
            wave_config: {
              sX: 0, // desplazamiento del eje x
              sY: 220 / 2,
              waveWidth: 0.015, // ancho de onda
              waveHeight: 5, // altura de ola
              axisLength: 220, // Longitud del eje
              speed: 0.09, // velocidad de onda
              xOffset: 0
            },
            circle_config: {
              r: 220 / 2, // centro del círculo
              cR: 220 / 2 - 5 // Radio
            },
            isLoading: false, // No muestra texto porcentual cuando isLoading es verdadero
            nowRange: 0,
            targetRange: 0,
            lineWidth: 2, // Ancho de línea circular
            data_range: [60, 80, 100], // rango de umbral de datos
            textColorRange: ['#fe5022', '#fff', '#fff'], // gama de colores de diferentes textos de umbral
            circle_line_color: ['#fe3702', '#ffa200', '#4ed752'], // diferente color de círculo de umbral
            main_backcolor_range: [
              ['#fe5e21', '#f98957'],
              ['#ffb30c', '#f7d35a'],
              ['#2ed351', '#8ced6c']
            ], // Gradiente
            backcolor_range: [
              ['#f76b3b', '#f14f17'],
              ['#f4d672', '#ffb50d'],
              ['#43ea83', '#12ce55']
            ]
          };
        if (!data) {
          var wave_config = {},
            circle_config = {};
          if (config.cvs_config) {
            wave_config = {
              sY: config.cvs_config.width / 2,
              axisLength: config.cvs_config.width
            };
            circle_config = {
              r: config.cvs_config.width / 2,
              cR: config.cvs_config.width / 2 - 5
            };
          }

          $.extend(true, _config, {
            wave_config: wave_config,
            circle_config: circle_config
          }, config);
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.width = _config.cvs_config.width;
          canvas.height = _config.cvs_config.height;
          $this.html("").html($(canvas));
          $this.data('waterBall', {
            canvas: canvas,
            target: $this,
            config: _config
          });
          methods.render.apply($this);
        }
      });
    },
    destroy: function() {},
    updateRange: function(newVal) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          data = $this.data('waterBall');
        if (!data) return;
        var config = $this.data('waterBall').config;
        config.targetRange = 0;
        // línea comentada para evitar que se actualice desde 0 cada vez
        //config.nowRange = 0; 
        config.isLoading = false;
        setTimeout(function() {
          config.targetRange = newVal;
        }, 0);
        
        // código que se ejecuta cuando termina de cargar 
        if (newVal == 100) {
          // hacemos fadeout del loader cuando termine la animación
          setTimeout(function() {
            $this.fadeOut();
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      var config = this.data('waterBall').config;
      var _canvas = this.data('waterBall').canvas;
      var w_sX = config.wave_config.sX,
        xOffset = config.wave_config.xOffset,
        bg_color1 = config.backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][0],
        bg_color2 = config.backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][1],
        main_bg_color1 = config.main_backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][0],
        main_bg_color2 = config.main_backcolor_range[getIndex.call(this)][1],
        ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');

      var cvs1 = drawCircle.call(this);

      if (config.nowRange <= config.targetRange) {
        var tmp = 1;
        config.nowRange += tmp;
      }

      if (config.nowRange > config.targetRange) {
        var tmp = 1;
        config.nowRange -= tmp;
      }
      var cvs2 = drawSin.call(this, xOffset + 40, bg_color1, bg_color2);
      var cvs3 = drawSin.call(this, -40 + xOffset, main_bg_color1, main_bg_color2);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, config.cvs_config.width, config.cvs_config.height);
      ctx.drawImage(cvs1, 0, 0);
      ctx.drawImage(cvs2, 0, 0);
      ctx.drawImage(cvs3, 0, 0);
      delete cvs1;
      delete cvs2;
      delete cvs3;

      config.wave_config.xOffset += config.wave_config.speed;
      requestAnimationFrame(methods.render.bind(this));
    }
  };
  $.fn.createWaterBall = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + 'does not exits on jQuery.createWaterBall');
    }
  };
})(jQuery);




/* Código del usuario */
var carga = 25;
$("img").on("load", function() {
    carga += 25;
    $('.waterBall1').createWaterBall('updateRange', carga);
});

$('.waterBall1').createWaterBall({
  csv_config: {
    width: $('.waterBall1').width(),
    height: $('.waterBall1').height()
  },
  wave_config: {
    waveWidth: 0.02,
    waveHeight: 5
  },
  data_range: [40, 50, 100],
  targetRange: carga
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<h1>jQuery createWaterBall Plugin Demos</h1>
<div class="waterBall1" style="width: 200px;height:200px; float:left"></div>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/cats" alt="Gato"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/people" alt="Gente"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nature" alt="Naturaleza"/>
```

Comment: he probado el código con las modificaciones que has realizado y si es cierto que ha mejorado, evoluciona linealmente hasta 100% 
 posteriormente se desvanece, pero aun le falta la "puntilla". Deseaba que el avance de carga del plugin se corresponda con el avance "REAL" de la carga de la pagina e imágenes y que llegue al 100% a la mima vez que termina de cargarse toda la pagina. Actualmente llega al 100% y se desvanece cuando aun no han terminado de cargarse todas las imágenes.

Comment: @Francisco Ok. A eso me refería con la parte de que cada vez que se cargue algo habría que actualizar el valor. Realmente la idea no es hacerlo lineal sino hacer un `updateRange` cada vez que se cargue algo (p.e. ficheros JS o imágenes). Ahora actualizo la respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: gracias. Has editado nuevamente el código como indicas? Aparentemente no encuentro ninguna diferencia con el anterior. Gracias

Comment: @Francisco edité la demo para añadir imágenes aleatorias y que el porcentaje cambie con cada imagen que se carga.

Comment: Alvaro, gracias por la ayuda. No obstante, estoy bastante verde en esto de los plugin, y no consigo entender el funcionamiento para adaptarlo a mi gusto y necesidades. Si no me equivoco, el código de usuario es necesario adaptarlo al numero de imágenes a descargar en la pagina, y si tengo varios enlaces en un menú, en cada una tendría que adaptarlo en función de las mismas. Desearía que pudiese ser común para todas ellas (independientemente del nº de imágenes). He visto algún otro plugin que funciona según la carga real y es independiente del numero de las imágenes, pero no se como adaptarlo.